# Why the answer to this question was deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers

Yesterday, I've asked [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/98510/44581) and I got an answer. I didn't accept it because I wanted to wait 24-48 hs before doing something (giving time to get another answers). But today, I see there isn't anymore an answer. What happened? Why he deleted his answer?

Comment: I deleted my own answer because I want to take time to edit it properly before to undelete it. I will need few days probably.

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C Ok

Comment: Undeleted. Still few things to correct and improve but it's better now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was explained in a comment on your question, the user who answered *elected* to delete their post.

Beyond the fact that the system recognizes it as self-deleted, we have no further information as to their rationale for doing so.

Comment: But his answer was actually fine. Could a moderator undelete it? I want to accept his answer!

Comment: There is a vote to undelete the post on the answer, but I am personally disinclined to override the user's choice to remove it.